# Should I implement my foreign key as an integer property or object reference in my model? (MVC)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship

Consider the following code snippet from my Student model:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

The 'Teacher' property is a foreign key in my DB. I want to know if the above implementation of that attribute is correct (as I use repositories to link the relevant student to the teacher) or should I be using the teacher object

```
public Teacher Teacher{get;set;}
```

to do this? In what circumstances would you want to use either of the two implementations?

Comment: Why not add both of them, so that you have the foreign key and the navigation property? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx.

Comment: By exposing a foreign key as a property, you're breaking the abstraction of an ORM. This has been discussed many times before, try searching.

Comment: From a practical perspective I've found it easiest to have both (TeacherId and Teacher class)  as this makes working with EF easier. From a design perspective, @CodeCaster is correct.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I see what you mean, so I should leave out the implementation of the FK in the Student model and simply make use of the relationship (with the Teacher model) when referencing the table in my repositories?

Comment: However, how would this relationship be referenced without an FK property in my Student model?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, you can use only class or you can use both(class and primitive). It also depends which ORM you are using. If you are using EntityFramework then

- If you use only object then when you insert new Student and you want
  assign teacher you must have an object.
- If you use both then when you create new Student you can set
  teacherId so you will "save one select"